# Django join different tables

Tags: django, django-models

This is what i got in the models

```
class SFE(models.Model):
snpid = models.ForeignKey(Snps, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SNPID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
elementid = models.ForeignKey(Functionalelement, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ElementID')  # Field name made lowercase.
celllineid = models.ForeignKey(Celllines, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CELLLINEID')  # Field name made lowercase.
countexperiments = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='countExperiments')  # Field name made lowercase.
filetype = models.CharField(db_column='fileType', max_length=10)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'SNPs_FunctionalElement'
    unique_together = (('snpid', 'elementid', 'celllineid', 'filetype'),)

def __str__(self):
    return str(str(self.snpid) + str(self.elementid) + str(self.celllineid) + str(self.filetype))

class Functionalelement(models.Model):
elementid = models.AutoField(db_column='ElementID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=55)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'FunctionalElement'

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.elementid)

class Snps(models.Model):
snpid = models.AutoField(db_column='SNPID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
rsid = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
chrom = models.CharField(max_length=5)
pos = models.PositiveIntegerField()
ref = models.CharField(max_length=1)
alt = models.CharField(max_length=1)
maf1000genomes = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
maftopmed = models.FloatField(db_column='mafTOPMed', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'SNPs'

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.snpid)
```

Now i want to join FunctionalElement with SFE in order to retrieve the field FunctionalElement.name given a specific SFE.snpid.

I tried with `SFE.objects.select_related('elementid__name')` but i know it's wrong and i can't understand how to work with django ORM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a simple object you need to do: `a = SFE.objects.get(snpid=THE_SPECIFICSNPID)` later you can access to all the related objects, for example: `a.elementid.name` will return what you want.
The Django ORM take retrieve the object for you, that is because "lazzy loading". That means that if you need a related object later Django will get it for you, of course, it need to do another query and to avoid that you need to call the method `select_related`

Summarizing:
To get the name you can do:

```
name = SFE.objects.get(snpid=THE_SPECIFICSNPID).select_related('elementid').elementid.name
```

It should works

Comment: It gives me an error which says 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: I tried with a = SnpsFunctionalelement.objects.get(Q(snpid=7) & Q(elementid=18)) followed by print(a.elementid_id.name) but it says 'int' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @MattiaCarolo yeap, of course, sorry I make a mistake, I forgot that it returns a SFE object and you need to navigate to the `Functionalelement` with the attribute `elementid`. I edited the post

Comment: Now it gives 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'elementid'. Think that i'll go back to old sql queries if I can i can't make it work

Comment: ok found an alternative way with a=SnpsFunctionalelement.objects.get(Q(snpid=7) & Q(elementid = 18)) followed by     b = a.elementid.name . Don't know how it works but still